# Jmeter - timeout exception

Tags: timeout, jmeter, httpresponse, connection-timeout, socket-timeout-exception

I ran a script for 100 concurrent users in NON - GUI mode

```
java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t  C:\XXX\JMeter\YYY\ZZZ.jmx -l C:\XXX\JMeter\ZZZ\testResult\log${__time(ddMMyy_HHmmss)}.jtl
```

I saved the JTL file generate during the run

After the run is complete, I loaded the JTL file in View Results Tree Listener
I could see few error as below:

Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Read timed out

Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect

Is there any problem with my JMeter script or is it something do with application connection.
Please help

Comment: This could mean that your execution platform cannot handle 100 threads, try starting with 10 and adding 10 until errors start showing up.

Comment: It shows the saem error for 30 concurrent users also. What should I do to run without this kind of errors

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with your application. It indicated your aplication is no more responsive and refuse connections or is long to answer to connections.
Did you put some Timers in your JMeter script, maybe you are too violent in your load.